# Cannot record sensor data using rosbag from kinect

Tags: ros, rosbag, openni-node, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I tried to record the data from Kinect by using `rosbag record -a` after I opened the openni_node driver for Kinect.

```
wei@wei-Aspire-4810T:~/ros/bagfiles$ roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch
```

Then in another terminal I used rosbag trying to record all topics:

```
wei@wei-Aspire-4810T:~/ros/bagfiles$ rosbag record -a
[ INFO] [1330246493.151671247]: Recording to 2012-02-26-16-54-53.bag.
[ INFO] [1330246494.158586547]: Subscribing to /camera/depth/image
[ INFO] [1330246494.163723907]: Subscribing to /camera/rgb/image_raw
[ INFO] [1330246494.167274829]: Subscribing to /camera/rgb/image_mono/compressed
[ INFO] [1330246494.169913071]: Subscribing to /camera/rgb/image_mono/compressed/parameter_updates
[ INFO] [1330246494.180194984]: Subscribing to /camera/depth/image/theora
[ INFO] [1330246494.185385283]: Subscribing to /camera/depth/image_raw/theora
[ INFO] [1330246494.199527654]: Subscribing to /tf
[ INFO] [1330246494.205979210]: Subscribing to /camera/depth/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
[ INFO] [1330246494.212827463]: Subscribing to /camera/rgb/image_mono/theora/parameter_descriptions
[ INFO] [1330246494.219018234]: Subscribing to /camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed
[ INFO] [1330246494.223620402]: Subscribing to /camera/rgb/image_mono/compressed/parameter_descriptions
[ INFO] [1330246494.226451684]: Subscribing to /camera/rgb/image_mono/theora/parameter_updates
[ INFO] [1330246494.229063037]: Subscribing to /camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
[ INFO] [1330246494.231719646]: Subscribing to /camera/depth/image/theora/parameter_updates
[ INFO] [1330246494.234358167]: Subscribing to /openni_node1/parameter_updates
[ INFO] [1330246494.236913228]: Subscribing to /camera/depth/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
[ INFO] [1330246494.239575774]: Subscribing to /camera/rgb/points
[ INFO] [1330246494.242255780]: Subscribing to /camera/rgb/camera_info
[ INFO] [1330246494.244859171]: Subscribing to /camera/rgb/image_color/compressed
[ INFO] [1330246494.261203557]: Subscribing to /camera/rgb/image_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
[ INFO] [1330246494.267427571]: Subscribing to /camera/depth/image/compressed
[ INFO] [1330246494.273242877]: Subscribing to /camera/depth/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
[ INFO] [1330246494.283536873]: Subscribing to /camera/depth/image_raw/compressed
[ INFO] [1330246494.291459070]: Subscribing to /camera/rgb/image_color/theora/parameter_updates
[ INFO] [1330246494.299466124]: Subscribing to /camera/depth/camera_info
[ INFO] [1330246494.302353488]: Subscribing to /camera/rgb/image_color
[ INFO] [1330246494.328684988]: Subscribing to /camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
[ INFO] [1330246494.337562469]: Subscribing to /rosout
[ INFO] [1330246494.349211658]: Subscribing to /camera/depth/disparity
[ INFO] [1330246494.352240939]: Subscribing to /camera/depth/image_raw
[ INFO] [1330246494.359652878]: Subscribing to /camera/rgb/image_color/compressed/parameter_updates
[ INFO] [1330246494.372313713]: Subscribing to /rosout_agg
[ INFO] [1330246494.380340812]: Subscribing to /camera/depth/image/theora/parameter_descriptions
[ INFO] [1330246494.386094727]: Subscribing to /camera/rgb/image_mono
[ INFO] [1330246494.392173263]: Subscribing to /camera/rgb/image_color/theora
[ INFO] [1330246494.400247295]: Subscribing to /camera/rgb/image_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
[ INFO] [1330246494.410299151]: Subscribing to /camera/depth/points
[ INFO] [1330246494.419197515]: Subscribing to /camera/rgb/image_raw/theora
[ INFO] [1330246494.425615758]: Subscribing to /camera/rgb/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
[ INFO] [1330246494.432190793]: Subscribing to /camera/depth/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
[ INFO] [1330246494.455170068]: Subscribing to /camera/rgb/image_mono/theora
[ INFO] [1330246494.466239857]: Subscribing to /camera/rgb/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
[ INFO] [1330246494.478321710]: Subscribing to /camera/depth/image/compressed/parameter_updates
[ INFO] [1330246494.484514087]: Subscribing to /openni_node1/parameter_descriptions
[ INFO] [1330246494.494957891]: Subscribing to /camera/depth/image/compressed/parameter_descriptions
^C
```

However, the openni_node crushed immediately after I started recording all topics. The error messages were:

```
OpenCV Error: Image step is wrong () in cvInitMatHeader, file /tmp/buildd/libopencv-2.3.1+svn6514+branch23/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 162
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /tmp/buildd/libopencv-2.3.1+svn6514+branch23/modules/core/src/array.cpp:162: error: (-13)  in function cvInitMatHeader

[openni_node1-2] process has died [pid 13733, exit code -6].
log files: /home/wei/.ros/log/7efa7378-6057-11e1-bb4c-fd7118ed2e09/openni_node1-2*.log
```

Is there anything I do wrong?

Thanks for answering!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28527/cannot-record-sensor-data-using-rosbag-from-kinect/) by [Mchaiiann](https://answers.ros.org/users/1388/mchaiiann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2012-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Don't use the -a flag, rosbag will subscribe to **all** offered topics, even if some are meant as alternatives and might not be used in combination.
So, think about what you want to do with the data and only subscribe to the relevant topics. The most commonly used topics are

- /tf
- /camera/rgb/image_mono
- /camera/rgb/image_color
- /camera/rgb/points
- /camera/rgb/camera_info
- /camera/depth/image
- /camera/depth/points
- /camera/depth/camera_info

But still you will only need a subset of those.

Edit: I just stumbled upon this again and want to add, that I recently wrote a small tool to assemble point clouds from (rgb and) depth images. It can be found [in our repository](http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/freiburg_tools/rgbd2cloud/). [The wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbd2cloud) will be generated in a few page. Until then have a look into the manifest for usage information.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mchaiiann](https://answers.ros.org/users/1388/mchaiiann/) on 2012-02-26**:
Thanks. Besides, why I said "openni_node crushed" is that the bag file only recorded some info or parameter_description instead of the real sensor data.
But why did this happened? (Should I open a new question for this?)
Now I specify the topics I want and this don't happened again. Thanks a lot.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-02-26**:
@Felix Endres is right. Note that you can save space in the bags by saving compressed images like /camera/rgb/image_image/compressed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Felix Endres is right. You should not try to record all the topics at the same time.

And if you are going to capture Kinect-Data it is worth having a look at the bandwidth of the topics in advance. When working at 640x480/30 fps the /camera/rgb/points topic will generate almost 300 MByte/s of data. That would lead to really huge bag-files... If you need the pointclouds later on you should consider capturing the raw image topics and reassemble the clouds on playback like described in [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/27921/kinect-how-do-i-convert-depth-image-to-pointcloud).

It may be necessary though to switch to the newer openni_launch for this to work. I am not sure if the older openni_camera driver can be broken up in single nodelets.

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2012-02-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mchaiiann](https://answers.ros.org/users/1388/mchaiiann/) on 2012-03-05**:
Hi, I'm wondering what you mean by saying "if the older openni_camera driver can be broken up in single nodelets."
Thanks.

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2012-03-05**:
The answer i linked relies on the fact, that the newer openni-driver has the different functions organized in nodelets which dont need to run in the same process and can be distributed. I dont know if the old driver supports the pointcloud-generation on another machine.